# React JS - Reading configurations from external property file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, properties-file

**Current Scenario**

I have a react app that is deployed on a JBoss server, now this deployed war file has some **axios calls**, that gets data from **backend** server **deployed war** file.

Now, the **port and IP** of this **backend** server is **hard-coded in axios calls**, and presently **can't be changed dynamically**. example:- axios.get('http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/api/warehouses')

**Desired Scenario**

Now, we need that after deploying our React App if our backend deployment changes to let say Server - **176.153.xxx.xxx:9000** from **192.168.xxx.xxx:8080**, we **don't need to re-deploy our frontend code**,
So we can directly read ip and port from property or json file.

---

So, now if I make a **property or json file inside SRC** in react project, then import this file and read values, it works fine, but after building with npm run build, I am not able to update this property or json file.

So I searched and found about environment variables, but they are also not the solution.

Found this link, but it also creates json file inside src.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-store-and-read-configuration-files-using-react

So, can this be achieved, if so what would the approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Just put the configuration file into your public folder. From inside React you can load it using axios: `axios.get("/config.json")` (also, environment variables are absolutely the generic solution to this, why would you think otherwise?)

Comment: About environment variables, I read it somewhere that, there values are set at the time of building build folder of react app, after that there values can only be read.

Comment: A built React app is just a bunch of static files that get served, for instance by Apache or node. So when we're talking about environment variables, we're talking about the server, not the React app. Passing data to the built app is as simple as inserting `<script>const serverURL = "...";</script>` into your React app's index.html. Or using any other method, like using `index.php` instead and reading an `.env` file and dumping it into the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Like Chris G commented, you can make a json file and load it in your javascript file, buuuuut I recommend use dependency injection and factory for this case.

Here goes a exempla:

First I created a json file in config folder:
https://github.com/lesimoes/COVID-MG/blob/master/config/env.prod.json

Then I created a factory that load the config file and inject in service, in this case SQS Service:
https://github.com/lesimoes/COVID-MG/blob/master/src/factories/queueFactory.js#L3

You can change values from json file without need deploy your application, but I guess you will need restarted it.